# Apps Script ReferenceError: eventCal is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I created this function

```
function createEvent() {
    emailList = ['test@gmail.com','test1@gmail.com','test2@gmail.com'];
    var startTime = new Date('Feb  11, 2021 12:00:00 EST');
    var endTime = new Date('Feb 11, 2021 14:00:00 EST');
    var description = "Here is the link for the webinar: "; 
    var event = {'location': '','description': description,'guests':emailList+',', 'sendInvites':'True'};
    eventCal.createEvent(summary, startTime, endTime, event).setGuestsCanSeeGuests(false);

}
```

But when I try running the script from the editor I see this error

> ReferenceError: eventCal is not defined (line 7, file "Code")

Can somebody please help

Comment: I think you want to replace `eventCal` with `CalendarApp` and it will solve your issue.

Comment: Oh thank you Marios! You saved my bacon!